# A powershell script that matches files names from a .csv file column then copies and renames them from another column if found

Tags: powershell

I am need of some assistance with a powershell script. My goal is that I have a hundreds of images with that are named wrong. I Have a csv file with the old names and the new names in two columns. I am trying to read the data from the first column(old names) and match what is in the images folder and then take those that match and rename them with the new names and copy in a new folder. Here is what I have below.

**Example Data**

| OldNames | NewNames |
| --- | --- |
| 1002 | 10001 |

```
$imagesDataPath = "C:\Images\ImagesData.csv"
$oldNamesData = (Import-CSV $imagesDataPath).OldNames
$newNamesData = (Import-CSV $imagesDataPath).NewNames
$imageFilesPath = "C:\Images\ImagesFolder"
$imageFiles = (Get-ChildItem "$imageFilesPath").Name
$newDirectory = New-Item -Path "C:\Images" -Name "Converted_Images" -ItemType Directory

foreach ($name in $oldNameData)
{
    if ($name -match $imageFiles)
    {
        Copy-Item $name -Destination $newDirectory\$newNamesData
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "not copied"
    }
}
```

All I keep getting is Not Copied even though I know there is current images that match with the old names that is in the OldNames column.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The first part of your question makes it sound like you're reading both the old and new names from the same CSV - but in your sample code you read from two different files... what's up with that?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen whoops! that was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out and I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop splitting your data apart! You've got a nice link (they belong to the same row in the CSV) between the old and new names right now, don't remove that!

```
$imagesDataPath = "C:\Images\ImagesData.csv"
# read all the rows into a single array, don't split each object into separate strings
$nameData = Import-CSV $imagesDataPath

$imageFilesPath = "C:\Images\ImagesFolder"

$newDirectory = New-Item -Path "C:\Images" -Name "Converted_Images" -ItemType Directory

foreach ($row in $nameData) {
    # use the record data to locate the old file
    $oldPath = Join-Path $imageFilesPath $row.OldNames
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $oldPath) {
        # we found a file matching the old name!
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $oldPath -Destination "${newDirectory}\$($row.NewNames)" # extract the new name from the current row
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "not copied"
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call. Thank you! However seems I am running into an issue when running that with that where it attempts to copy the foldername "ImagesFolder" multiple times and fails stating it already exists multiple times. I tried creating the new directory before copy-item. so instead of the $newDirectory variable with New-Item I just added the New-Item cmdlet in the foreach before Copy-Item and then in Copy-Item, I specified the new directory in Copy-Item -LiteralPath $oldPath -Destination "C:\Images\Converted_Images\$($row.NewNames)" but even that doesn't find the files and instead get Not Copied.

Comment: @Chimpin Try changing `"${newDirectory}\$($row.NewNames)"` to `(Join-Path $newDirectory.FullName $row.NewNames)` - `"$newDirectory"` will expand to the folder name in WPS, not the full path

Comment: That did it! Runs amazingly now. Thank you so much for your time and help!